# Grunt babel is not transforming arrow functions for IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, gruntjs, babeljs

How do i include babel with browserify in a legacy grunt build to transform es6 code?

Comment: Have you tried loading the [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/#usage-in-browser) in your .html via à <script> tag?

Comment: @RobC yes I did include babel-polyfill as a cdnjs script tag in the index.html.

Comment: In your `.babelrc` the _Babel preset_ should be defined as `{ "presets": ["es2015-ie"] }` and not `plugins` - as shown [here](https://github.com/jmcriffey/babel-preset-es2015-ie#usage)

Comment: @RobC I changed it but still nothing.

Comment: ...and the `polyfill.js` loads via `index.html` _before_ all other transpiled `.js` scripts?

Comment: @RobC yes I did. I also updated the question to include a screenshot of the polyfill.js

Comment: I've noticed that you have `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions` listed as a `devDependencies` in _package.json_. I'm not sure why you would need that, however try adding it as a `plugin` to your `.babelrc` so it reads: `{"presets": ["es2015-ie"], "plugins": ["transform-es2015-arrow-functions"]}` _(further info [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions/#via-babelrc-recommended))_

Comment: May also be worth trying to replace the `babel-preset-env` package with [@babel/preset-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/preset-env) and targeting IE11 specifically using the `targets: {...}` property in your `.babelrc` - further info about this [here](https://new.babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-preset-env.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
In `gruntfile.js` add the following code and note that it needs autopolyfiller dependency:

```
grunt.initConfig({
autopolyfiller: {
    latest_browsers_and_ie: {
        options: {
            browsers: ['last 2 version', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'ie 11']
        },
        files: {
            'www/file_with_all_polyfills.js': ['your/js/**/*.js']
        }
    }
}
});
```